# Printing Integer Contents of a Vector as a String are Leading to Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vector, random, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to print my normal distribution by using consecutive '*' characters to reflect the bars of the normal distribution. The program crashes often before it is printed, but sometimes after. Any idea what is going on?

```
int main() {
std::normal_distribution<double> normDist(10.0, 4.0); 
    vector<int> v(20); // All zeros.
    for (int i{}; i < 500; i++) {
        int num = normDist(eng3);
        if (num >= 0 && num < 20);
            v[num]++;
    }

    for (int i{}; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << i << ": " << std::string(v[i], '*') << endl;
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```
0: *****
1: ***
2: *******
3: *******
4: ***********************
5: *********************
6: **********************************
7: **********************************
8: ********************************************
9: ********************************************
10: ****************************************************
11: **********************************************
12: *****************************************
13: **************************************************
14: ************************************
15: *******************
16: ************
17: ********
18: *******
19: **
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `if (num >= 0 && num < 20);` -- You have a semicolon here.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good catch

Comment: You also should post a [mcve].  You are missing `#include`s, the definition of `eng3`,...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for that catch, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra semicolon here:

```
if (num >= 0 && num < 20);   // <- extra semicolon results in empty body
  v[num]++;
```

as @PaulMcKenzie spotted. This code has the same effect as this code:

```
if (num >= 0 && num < 20)
{
  // nothing here
}
v[num]++;
```

So what happens is that you index your vector with `num` as your index, without checking if the values are in range.

As a result, since the values `num` gets are random, sometimes you might end up accessing memory out of bounds (of the vector), thus cause a segmentation fault for example, which invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB).

That probably explains why your code crashes some times, and others not.